# How to consume JSON in Express JS?

Tags: node.js, json, express, request

In very new to **express js**. I just wrote a simple program to send JSON request through postman and get the response.

Why I can't get any response? it always says could not get any response. I go through several tutorials and could not figure out what exact missing here?. Here is my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

    app.use(express.json);
    app.post('/',  (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send(req.body);
    });

    app.listen(3000, () =>{
        console.log("Listen in port 30000");
    });
```

Comment: you just need to parse your body data with a package. body-parser.json()
check my answer for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out what went wrong. Here

```
app.use(express.json);
```

Should be This,

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your json data inorder to consume it. 
check the following code.

> install this package. 
>   **npm i body-parser**

and use it with your express object as below

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: I figure out what went wrong. As I'm using express 4.17 version I can directly use app.use(express.json());

Comment: @Dasun, that's great. if this really helped you, you can mark the answer right.